# how to make an html document appear within another html document on a click of a button, and styling it

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, colors

im making a program that generates rgb, hsl, and hex# colors in 6 swatches, the other 5 swatches being complementary light and darker colors. I need to have a button that when pushed inserts another html file (something very basic that has some styling) and then another button that when pushed styles the example html file previously inserted with the colors the user inputed.

a simple way to put it is basically to show the user how the colors generated would look on an example website page. So on the new html file, the new colors generated would display for the user to see. Like the font color would change, toolbars, calendar, anything like that.

How would I go about doing this? my code generates the colors, and I inserted an  so I can see my sample website, I just dont know how to style the css of the example html code. any suggestions would work perfect! I dont know how to attach files on this website but if you need me to email you all my code I can do that. just let me know thank you!

Comment: You've got a lot of questions here. It would be better if you could ask separate specific questions rather than asking for help on every aspect of your project in one overly broad question.

Answer (score 0):

> An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current
>   HTML document.

http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info.  Seems reasonable to be upset with them.  However, I have found there stuff to be succinct reference and correct on the everyday stuff.  I'll certainly search for an alternative though...

Comment: @DerekLitz w3schools might have its pitfalls but it is not a bad resource... it's way too commonly bashed for the wrong reasons. It is an incredibly helpful resource; one which I still frequently use.

Answer (score 0):

Like Derek said, iframes are used for inserting pages or parts of pages into other pages, but I'd say it'd make more sense for you to use a div rather than an entire new HTML page.